# Cannot create table in SQL Compact with Foreign Key

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-ce

First time using this database because I need a type that's portable and so far it's been a headache. I can't seem to figure out what's wrong with the code.

Here's what I'm trying to run - it's in Spanish but you get the gist of it:

```
create table UsuarioRol
(
UsuarioRolId int primary key identity(1,1),
Nombre nvarchar(64) not null,
NivelAutoridad int not null
)

create table Usuario
(
UsuarioId int primary key identity(1,1),
UsuarioRolId int foreign key references UsuarioRol(UsuarioRolId),
Login nvarchar(64) not null,
Password nvarchar(64) not null
)
```

I get the error:

> --------------------------- Microsoft Visual Studio
>   --------------------------- SQL Execution Error.
>
> Executed SQL statement: create table UsuarioRol
>
> (
>
> UsuarioRolId int primary key identity(1,1),
>
> Nombre nvarchar(64) not null,
>
> NivelAutoridad int not null
>
> )
>
> create table Usuario
>
> (
>
> UsuarioId int primary key identity(1,1),,
>
> UsuarioRolId int foreign key references Usua... Error Source: SQL
>   Server Compact ADO.NET Data Provider Error Message: There was an error
>   parsing the query. [ Token line number = 8,Token line offset = 1,Token
>   in error = create ]
>
> ### --------------------------- OK   Help

I don't understand what might be wrong in the syntax. Am I missing something here?

Even tried this, and I get the same error.

Running the exact same TSQL on a regular ol' SQL Server database, runs perfectly.

Can I conclude that SQL Compact doesn't support foreign keys?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if that syntax is supported with SQL Server CE.  The following should work:

```
create table UsuarioRol
(
UsuarioRolId int primary key identity(1,1),
Nombre nvarchar(64) not null,
NivelAutoridad int not null
);
GO

create table Usuario
(
UsuarioId int primary key identity(1,1),
UsuarioRolId int,
Login nvarchar(64) not null,
Password nvarchar(64) not null
)
GO

ALTER TABLE [Usuario] ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Usario_UsarioRol]
    FOREIGN KEY ([UsuarioRolId]) REFERENCES [UsuarioRol]([UsuarioRolId]);
GO
```

**Update:**

Actually, what you had should work, just remove "foreign key" in the syntax:

```
create table UsuarioRol
(
UsuarioRolId int primary key identity(1,1),
Nombre nvarchar(64) not null,
NivelAutoridad int not null
);
GO

create table Usuario
(
UsuarioId int primary key identity(1,1),
UsuarioRolId int references UsuarioRol(UsuarioRolId),
Login nvarchar(64) not null,
Password nvarchar(64) not null
);
GO
```

Or this should also work:

```
create table UsuarioRol
(
UsuarioRolId int primary key identity(1,1),
Nombre nvarchar(64) not null,
NivelAutoridad int not null
);
GO

create table Usuario
(
UsuarioId int primary key identity(1,1),
UsuarioRolId int,
Login nvarchar(64) not null,
Password nvarchar(64) not null,
foreign key (UsuarioRolId) references UsuarioRol (UsuarioRolId)
);
GO
```

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173393(v=SQL.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can only run a single statement at a time with SQl Server Compact, so depending on the tool you use you must at least separate with GO and new line.

Answer (score 0):

Not this,

```
UsuarioRolId int foreign key references UsuarioRol(UsuarioRolId),
```

but this.

```
UsuarioRolId int references UsuarioRol(UsuarioRolId),
```